# How to achieve curved drop shadow effect with CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve the following drop shadow effect using CSS:

[image]

I have tried styling an `<hr>` element with a linear gradient as the background image as an alternative to using the `box-shadow` rule on an image however it does not produce the desired curved shadow effect.

Is what I am trying to do possible via CSS only ?

Here is my current code:

**HTML**

```
<section class="section-categories section-fruits">
    <div class="row">
        <figure class="categories">
            <img src="res/img/category/fruits.png" alt="Offers" class="categories__fruits">
        </figure>
        <div class="categories__explore">
            <p>Fruits & Vegetables</p>
            <p>A variety of fresh fresh and vegetables</p>
            <button>Explore fruit and veg</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Using Box Shadow, but didn't get the desired effect */    
.section-categories{
    height: 250px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: what effect are you talking about??

Comment: @XenioGracias The greyish bottom shadow effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One pure CSS approach might be to use the [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) function on a pseudo element as follows:

```css
/* The shadow CSS class element */
.shadow {
  position:relative;
}

/* The CSS peseudo element that achieves the shadow effect */
.shadow:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-1rem;
  /* The main idea with this technique is to use a radial gradient to simulate the 
  desired effect */
  background:radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 50% 0px, grey 0%, transparent 50%);
  width:100%;
  height:1rem;
  
}

/* The styling below is not part of the technique and is included to support the snippet */
div {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

div button {
  background:red;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/1c/f5/2b1cf5525873467315eaa0c07394d302.jpg" height="100px" />
<button>Explore</button>
</div>
```

The idea here is to define a pseudo element `:after` the actual element casting the shadow (ie the `<div>` in the snippet above), which contains a `radial-gradient`. To simulate the desired effect, the `radial-gradient` is colored with a dark inner and transparent outer, with the center of that gradient being offset to the upper edge of the pseudo element via the [`farthest-corner at 50% 0px`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient#Syntax) parameters.

Hope that helps